# Creating VPC Link for an internal NLB that already has a VPC endpoint service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, nlb

I have an internal NLB that has an associated VPC Endpoint Service. Now I want to expose the NLB via a publicly accessible API Gateway. When I try to create a "VPC Link", I get the error that there is already an VPC Endpoint Service associated with the NLB. How do I create a "VPC Link" to that NLB?

Alternatively: how can I expose my internal NLB to the internet? (If using API Gateway doesn't work due to the above restriction).

Comment: Follow this article https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-fix-nlb-associated-with-service/ to disassociate the VPC endpoint from the load balancer, then try to create the VPC link again

Comment: There are clients who use the existing VPC endpoint service. Wouldn't this break things for them?